# Voice-over Recordist correct Title?

Tags: title, job-description

Hey! What is the correct Title of someome that records Voice-overs for films/ads... The technical Job! And the One that you would read in the Credits

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the soundie manning the controls then voice over recordist would do just nicely!

Answer (score 2):

Voice-over recordist or Recording engineer is fine. I record VOs for TV and radio spots and am called a recording engineer. However, I can't remember ever appearing in any credits for it.

Comment: I am making a List with all the projects i worked on with all the jobs i did. I make that list to improve my CV!

Comment: Engineer ?      .

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the "recording engineer" title. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineer

Answer (score -3):

'Narrator', or 'narration by' or narration

Sometimes 'commentary by' or 'commentary'

Or as a job title 'voice-over artist',

Comment: A voice-over artist surely is not concerned with recording, but acts. The other titles you mention are also voice-over artist titles. I would credit the REC button presser solely as "voice-over recording (by X)".

Comment: These days a great many VO artists work out of their home studios, connecting to the client via ISDN or Source Connect, so they are concerned with recording. They also are often asked to do the editing as well.

But you're right, most of those titles don't answer the OPs question.